# Facebook SDK user_posts: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to fetch user posts with FB SDK but get an error. Any idea what is wrong?

```
let gr2 : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "user_posts", parameters: nil)
gr2.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result2, error) -> Void in

})
```

Error I get is:

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=803, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 803;
            "fbtrace_id" = "Fo/ky5BIe7W";
            message = "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: user_posts";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 404;
}, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=404, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: user_posts, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_posts` is a permission, not an API endpoint.

You need to authorize users with `user_posts` and use the `/me/posts` endpoint to get user posts.

You really need to take a look at the docs once in a while, there is even example code for everything: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed

Make sure you understand the difference between a permission and an API endpoint.